# declare variable named as string+integer value

Tags: c#, string, merge, tabcontrol, tabpage

I want to add tabpages to tabcontrol1,
and need to have tabpages created dynamically

```
 int a=10;
 TabPage tabpage"+a+" = new TabPage();
```

How can i achieve this :

```
tabpage10
tabpage12
tabpage13
```

created dynamically

Comment: You cannot, simply create the tabpage and add to tabcontrol.

Comment: i want tabpage to be created having name as "string"+int

Answer (score 6):

You can't, and you shouldn't try to. Instead, either have an array or list (if your numbers are all positive, effectively starting near 0) or a `Dictionary<int, TabPage>` for a more general mapping.

Whenever you find you have a *collection* of values, you should reach for a *collection* type - rather than a lot of different variables which happen to have names starting with a common prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically generate variable names - and nor would you want to.  Instead, consider adding the tab page to a collection.

```
List<TabPage> tabs = new List<TabPage>();
tabs.Add(new TabPage()); // 0
tabs.Add(new TabPage()); // 1
tabs.Add(new TabPage()); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in winforms:

```
int a = 10;
tabcontrol1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("text") { Name = "tabpage" + a });
a++;
```

Then to access

```
var page = tabcontrol1.TabPages[0];
```

or by name

```
var page = tabcontrol1.TabPages["tabpage" + a];
```

Comment: name.BackgroundImage does not work 

i need something like this TabPage mynewtab+some_integer_value= new TabPage();

Comment: `page.BackgroundImage` simply find it by index